# How to use relayoutData in the dash app to zoom into graph and maintain the zoom for new data

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have build a dash application. There are two graphs in the dashboard. So I was trying to implement relayoutdata function in the dashboard so that user can zoom in those graphs and maintain the zoom by not reloading the graphs and preserve the state for new data points.

The code which I was trying to implement is below -

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
#callback for buttons

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('buttons', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('button-1', 'n_clicks'),
               dash.dependencies.Input('button-2', 'n_clicks'),
               dash.dependencies.Input('button-4', 'n_clicks')
              ])

def displayClick(btn1,btn2,btn4):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'button-2' in changed_id:
        return html.Div(children = [

        html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'lineSelect1',
                options = lineOptions,
                placeholder = 'Select Line',
                clearable=False,
                style = dropdownStyle,
            )), html.Div(dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='date_picker',
        min_date_allowed=date(2020, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=date.today()+timedelta(days=1),
        initial_visible_month=date.today()-timedelta(days=1),
        start_date=date.today()-timedelta(days=1),
        end_date=date.today(),
        style = dropdownStyle1

    )),
            html.Div(id='AlarmHistory'),
        ])

    elif 'button-4' in changed_id:
        path = "C:/Users/ISLAMS/Downloads/Work/Project Fusion/Plating Lines Code/Lincoln Files/"
        extension = 'xlsx'
        os.chdir(path)
        result = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
        result = [sub.replace('.xlsx','') for sub in result]
        sheetOptions = [{'label' :i,'value' :i } for i in result]


        return html.Div([

        dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'sheetSelect1',
                options = sheetOptions,
                value = result[0],
                placeholder = 'Select Line',
                clearable=False,
                style = dropdownStyle1,
            ),

         html.Div(id='editTable'),

     ])
    else:
        return html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'lineSelect',
                options = lineOptions,
                multi = True,
                placeholder = 'Select Lines',
                clearable=True,
                value = td2[0].unique(),
                style = dropdownStyle,
            ),
            html.Br(),
            html.Div(id='table'),
            dcc.Interval(id='refresh-table',
                        interval = 120000,
                        n_intervals = 0,
                        max_intervals=99999999999),
        ])


#call back for All Plating Lines

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('table', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('lineSelect', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('refresh-table', 'n_intervals'),])

def filter_table(input,num):
    if num == 99999999999:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        print ("The code is inside the function")
        df2 = pd.read_sql_query(query_3, engine)
        df2['location'] = df2['location'].replace(regex='AmpsActual',value='')
        df2['line'] = np.where(df2.location.str[3] == '1' ,df2.line+' 1',df2.line)
        df2['line'] = np.where(df2.location.str[3] == '2' ,df2.line+' 2',df2.line)

        tableData = df2.pivot_table('alarmflag',['line','linespeed'],'location',aggfunc = 'first')
        tableData = pd.DataFrame(tableData.to_records())
        tableData.columns = [hdr.replace("('alarmflag',","").replace(")","") for hdr in tableData.columns]

        td1 = tableData
        td1['linespeed'] = td1['linespeed'].round(1)
        td1['linespeed'] = td1['linespeed'].astype(str)


        for j in td1.columns:
            if j not in ['line','linespeed']:
                td1[j] = j + td1[j]

        sort0_cols = td1.columns[td1.columns.str.contains(pat="EC")  ]
        sort1_cols = td1.columns[td1.columns.str.contains(pat="Ni")  ]
        sort2_cols = td1.columns[td1.columns.str.contains(pat="Ag")  ]
        sort3_cols = td1.columns[td1.columns.str.contains(pat="Sn")  ]
        sort4_cols = td1.columns[(~td1.columns.str.contains(pat="EC") & ~td1.columns.str.contains(pat="Ni") &
                                  ~td1.columns.str.contains(pat="Ag") & ~td1.columns.str.contains(pat="Sn") &
                                  ~td1.columns.str.contains(pat="line") ) ]
        td1 = pd.concat([td1['line'],td1['linespeed'],td1[sort0_cols],td1[sort1_cols],td1[sort2_cols],td1[sort3_cols],td1[sort4_cols]],axis=1)
        td1['new'] = td1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()),axis=1)
        td2 = td1['new'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.split(',')))
        td2.rename(columns = {0:'line'},inplace=True)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data = td2)
        dfFiltered = pd.DataFrame()
        temp = input

        dfFiltered = df[df.line.isin(temp)]

        return html.Div([
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id='tab',
                columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dfFiltered.columns],
                data = dfFiltered.to_dict('records'),

                style_cell={'maxWidth': 0,
                            'overflow': 'hidden',
                            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
                            'textAlign': 'center',
                            'font-family': 'Verdana',
                            'margin':'10px',
                            'font-weight': 'bold',
                            },
                style_header = {'display': 'none'},
                style_data_conditional = ([{'if':{'filter_query': '{{{col}}} is blank'.format(col=col),
                                                  'column_id' : col},
                                            'backgroundColor': 'white',
                                            'color': 'white' } for col in dfFiltered.columns] +
                                          [{'if':{'filter_query': '{{{col}}} contains "."'.format(col=col),
                                                  'column_id' : col},
                                            'backgroundColor': '#CC0000',
                                            'color': 'white' } for col in dfFiltered.columns] +
                                          [{'if':{'filter_query': '{{{col}}} contains "`"'.format(col=col),
                                                  'column_id' : col},
                                            'backgroundColor': 'white',
                                            'color': 'green' } for col in dfFiltered.columns] +
                                          [{'if':{'filter_query': '{{{col}}} contains " "'.format(col=col),
                                                  'column_id' : col},
                                            'backgroundColor': '#D3D3D3',
                                            'color': 'black' } for col in dfFiltered.columns]
                                           +  [{'if':{
                                                   'column_id' : 1},
                                             'backgroundColor': '#D3D3D3',
                                             'color': 'black' }]
                                          ),
                )
            ,   dcc.Graph(id="graph3", style={"width": "50%", "display": "inline-block"}),
            dcc.Graph(id="graph4", style={"width": "50%", "display": "inline-block"}),])


#call back for selection on All Plating Lines

@app.callback(
    [Output('graph3', 'figure'),Output('graph4', 'figure')],
    [Input('tab', 'derived_virtual_data'),Input('tab', 'active_cell')])

def show_graph(rows, selection):

    dff = pd.DataFrame(rows)

    if selection is None:
        n_intervals = 0
        return {}, {}
    else:
        n_intervals = 99999999999
        loc = dff.iloc[selection['row']][selection['column']-1]
        loc = loc.replace('.','').replace('`','').replace(' ','').replace('AmpsActual','')
        input1 = loc + 'AmpsActual'
        t1 = dff.iloc[selection['row']]['line']
        input2 = t2 = t1[:3]
        t1 = 'USMLXLIUP_' + t2


        cnxn_1 = mysql.connector.connect(AWS Credentials)
        cursor = cnxn_1.cursor()

        query_4 = """Select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME = '{}'
        and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ppqa' and
        (COLUMN_NAME like '{}%' or COLUMN_NAME = 'DateTime' )
        order by ORDINAL_POSITION"""

        table_columns = pd.read_sql_query(query_4.format(t1,loc), cnxn_1)



        col_list = [i for i in table_columns['COLUMN_NAME']]
        col_string = ', '.join([str(i) for i in col_list])

        query_5 = """SELECT {},  '{}' as line, NOW() as lastrefreshdate
                FROM ppqa.{}
                where DateTime >= now() - interval 24 hour
                order by DateTime"""

        df = pd.read_sql_query(query_5.format(col_string,t2,t1), cnxn_1)

        if len(df) == 0:
            return {}, {}
        else:
            df['data point i'] = df.index + 1
            filename = t2
            volt_col = input1.replace('Amp','Volt')

            tolerance_inputs = pd.read_excel("/home/sislam/Sohail Islam/Adhoc/Project Fusion/Notebook/Lincoln Plating Lines/Files/"+filename +".xlsx", sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

            current_tolerance = int(tolerance_inputs["Current Tolerance for " + input1].loc[0])
            voltage_tolerance = int(tolerance_inputs["Voltage Tolerance for Standard Deviation for " + volt_col].loc[0])

            standard_dev_15_rows = df[df['data point i'] <= 15][volt_col].std()

            df['rolling_average']  = df[volt_col].rolling(15).mean()

            def func_voltage_mu_o(df):
                if df['data point i'] <= 15:
                    return (df[volt_col])
                else:
                    return (df['rolling_average'])

            df['voltage_mu_o'] = df.apply(func_voltage_mu_o, axis = 1)

            if input1.startswith("Ni"):
                Voltage_SD = 0.045
            elif input1.startswith("Sn"):
                Voltage_SD = 0.050
            elif input1.startswith("ECln"):
                Voltage_SD = 0.055
            elif input1.startswith("Ag"):
                Voltage_SD = 0.055
            else:
                Voltage_SD = 0.055

            df['voltage_sigma'] =  Voltage_SD


            fig=go.Figure()
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df[loc+'AmpsSetpoint'],name = 'Current Set Point',line=dict(color='black',width=4,dash='dash')))
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df[input1],name = 'Actual Current',line=dict(color='black',width=4)))
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df[loc+'AmpsSetpoint']+df[loc+'AmpsSetpoint']*current_tolerance/100,name = 'Upper Limit',line=dict(color='red',width=4)))
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df[loc+'AmpsSetpoint']-df[loc+'AmpsSetpoint']*current_tolerance/100,name = 'Lower Limit',line=dict(color='red',width=4)))
            fig.update_layout(title= input2+' '+input1[:5]+ ' : Current Vs Time',xaxis_title = 'Time',yaxis_title = 'Current (Amp)')

            fig2=go.Figure()
            fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df[loc+'VoltsActual'],name = 'Actual Voltage',line=dict(color='black',width=4)))
            fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df['voltage_mu_o'] + df['voltage_sigma'] * voltage_tolerance,name = 'Voltage Red UCL',line=dict(color='red',width=4)))
            fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'],y=df['voltage_mu_o'] - df['voltage_sigma'] * voltage_tolerance,name = 'Voltage Red LCL',line=dict(color='red',width=4)))
            fig2.update_layout(title= input2+' '+input1[:5]+ ' : Voltage Vs Time',xaxis_title = 'Time',yaxis_title = 'Voltage (Volt)')

            return fig, fig2

@app.callback(
    Output('refresh-table','n_intervals'),
    Input('tab', 'active_cell'))

def stop( selection):
    if selection is None:
        n_intervals = 0
        return n_intervals
    else:
        n_intervals = 99999999999
        return n_intervals    '''
```

Comment: Your code is too long to be minimal reproducing example. To zoom, you'd use `fig.update_xaxis(range=...)` (and/or yaxis counterpart). To maintain the zoom, use `Input("graph", "relayoutData")` and use that dictionary values to update the figure layout or axes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the  dcc.Graph: uirevision feature new to dash_core_components.  dash-core-components==0.39.0rc4. This will preserve the zoom area through a callback without resetting unless the uirevesion is changed.

https://community.plotly.com/t/preserving-ui-state-like-zoom-in-dcc-graph-with-uirevision-with-dash/15793?page=2